# Problema con Listas enlazadas ordenadas

Tags: c++

Tengo un problema al momento de insertar los datos de manera ordenada, tengo entendido que si inserto un 5 al inicio y posteriormente un 3 y después un 10, la lista quedaría 3->5->10, sé muy bien que en alguna parte del método **Insertar** algo hice mal, una declaración equivocada o error de lógica, pero no lo logro ver aun. así que necesito ayuda para poder resolver el problema que tengo.

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

class Nodo{
    int dato;
    Nodo *sig;
    Nodo *inicio;
    public:
        Nodo(){
            dato=0;
            inicio=sig= NULL;
        }
        void inserta(){
            Nodo *nuevo= new Nodo;
            Nodo *ind= inicio;
            nuevo->Lee();
            if(inicio==NULL)
                inicio=nuevo;
            else if(dato<=dato){ //si el nodo es menor
                nuevo->sig=inicio;
                inicio= nuevo;
            }
            else if(dato==dato){ //si el nodo es igual
                int num;
                num=dato;
                while (ind && ind ->dato != num)
                    ind= ind->sig;
                if(ind == NULL){
                    cout<<"\nNo se encontro el dato\n";
                }
                else{
                    nuevo->sig=ind->sig;
                    ind->sig=nuevo;
                    cout<<"\nNodo insertado correctamente por el medio\n";
                }
            }
            else if(dato>=dato){ //Si el nodo es mayor 
                while (ind->sig != NULL)
                    ind= ind->sig;
                ind->sig=nuevo;
                cout<<"\nNodo insertado al final";
            }  
        }
        void Muestra(){
            if(inicio==NULL)
                cout<<"\nLista vacia\n";
            else{
                Nodo *ind= inicio;
                cout<<"\nDatos de la lista\n";
                while (ind != NULL){
                    cout<<ind->dato<<'-> ';
                    ind= ind-> sig;
                }
            }
        } 
        void Lee(){
            cout<<"\nIngresa el dato: ";
            fflush(stdin);
            cin>>dato;
        }
        ~Nodo(){
            Nodo *ind;
            while (inicio){
                ind= inicio;
                inicio= inicio->sig;
                delete ind;
            } 
        }
};
```

El detalle: cuando acaba el programa estan mal ordenadas y siento que algo estoy haciendo mal desde el los **IF's**

Comment: Me parece que esto: `if(dato<=dato)` no tiene ningún sentido. Y tienes unos cuantos en la función `insertar`. Estás comparando una variable consigo misma.

Answer (score 1):

El diseño de tu "*lista*" está conceptualmente mal:

1. Los nodos de las listas enlazadas tienen punteros a los valores anteriores y siguientes, pero tu nodo tiene un puntero a `inicio` y `siguiente`. No tiene sentido que todos los nodos apunten al inicio de la lista, seguramente querías que los punteros fuesen `anterior` y `siguiente`.
2. Los nodos son objetos pasivos que almacenan datos y se enlazan entre si, les has dotado de funciones que no les corresponden como lectura e impresión de datos.
3. El destructor del nodo es la receta del desastre. Cuando llamas a `delete` invocas el destructor del nodo, por lo que en cada borrado haces una eliminación recursiva de nodos y acabas borrando (intentándolo más bien) nodos más de una vez.

Necesitas los siguientes cambios en tu código:

1. Crea un objeto `Lista` que gestione los nodos.
2. Los nodos deberán ser un tipo interno de la `Lista`.
3. La `Lista` se encargará de la inserción y borrado de datos, no los nodos.

Answer (score 0):

En la operación inserta estás comparando la varaible dato consigo misma así que siempre se cumplirá la primera condición:

```
else if(dato<=dato){ //si el nodo es menor
```